# Función buscar en listas enlazadas C

Tags: c

Tengo este condigo en el cual he intentado resolver mi problema con la función de buscar(en el cual intento buscar y mostrar un elemento de la lista enlazada), pero no consigo saber que es lo que pasa con ello

Me aparece un error que es:**exited,segmentation fault**

El resto del codigo está aquí si es que sirve como referencia : https://repl.it/@DonPepper/Catastro

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef char cadena[24];

typedef struct contagiado{
cadena rut;
cadena nombre; 
int edad;
int fechaDiagnostico;
cadena region;
struct contagiado*link;
} Nodo;
typedef Nodo *tpuntero;
typedef tpuntero catastro[16];
Nodo* Start = NULL;
Nodo* head = NULL;

Nodo *buscar(char rut[], Nodo *apuntador) {
  Nodo* ptr = apuntador;
  Nodo* anterior = NULL;
 while (ptr != NULL)
 {
   if( strcmp(ptr->rut, rut) == 0)
   {
     if( anterior )
       anterior->link = ptr->link;
     else
        apuntador = ptr->link; // el primer elemento de la lista se elimina         

     ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    else
    {
      anterior = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->link;
    }
  }
  return apuntador;
}
```

Esta es la forma en la que estoy llamando a la función:

```
     printf("Inserte Rut para buscar: \n");
       scanf("%s",rup);
     p = buscar(rup,head);
     if(p != NULL)
     printf("El rut de la persona es:  %s\n", p->rut);
     printf("Su region es: %s\n", p->region);
```

Nota:Los demás casos del menú son alternos y necesito saber buscar para avanzar :(

De antemano agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda

Comment: Ese error significa que estas accediendo a memoria que no te pertenece. Colocale una buena cantidad de logs, y compilalo con un address sanitizer. Asi veras en que momento es en el que estas leyedo memoria que no te toca.

Comment: ¿Cómo construyes la lista enlazada? puede que el problema esté ahí